# First-order ODE orbit and time domain

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Consider the autonomous Initial-Value Problem (IVP)
$$\dfrac {dx}{dt}=\dfrac 12(x^3−x)$$
$$
x(0) =x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$$

where x is a function of time. I am supposed to indicate the time domain over which the solution is defined. I guess it is related to the equilibrium point and orbit of the differential equation, but I am not sure how to find a restriction in the intervals.

Comment: The qualitative principles discussed in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3808538/prove-or-disprove-if-y-y-y2-and-y0-a-where-0a1-then-ayx-leq-1 can also be applied here. It is sufficient to determine the stationary solutions and the direction of the vector field in-between.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: all logarithm functions below have an absolute value function inside them as we work on the reals, unless specified otherwise.*

**If you were looking to describe how $\dot{x}$ changes (phase line):**

To find the equilibrium points of the Autonomous DE we need to find its roots in terms of $x$.

\begin{align}
\dfrac {dx}{dt}&=\dfrac 12(x^3−x):=f(x)\\
\dfrac {dx}{dt}&=\dfrac 12x(x^2−1)=\frac{1}{2}x(x-1)(x+1)
\end{align}

The roots of the equation (when $dx/dt=0$) are $x\in\{0, -1, 1\}$ .

Let's find the slope of the function at its roots(zeros):

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}f(x)&=\frac{1}{2}(3x^2-1)\\
\frac{d}{dx}f(-1)&=1\quad&\text{source}\\
\frac{d}{dx}f(0)&=-\frac{1}{2}\quad&\text{sink}\\
\frac{d}{dx}f(1)&=1\quad&\text{source}\\
\end{align*}
Phase line of the DE:
[image]

---

**If you actually want to find the domain of $t$**

The solution of the equation is:

\begin{align}
\dfrac {dx}{dt}&=\dfrac 12(x^3−x)\\
\int\dfrac{dx}{2(x^3-x)}&=\int dt\\
\frac{1}{2}\int\left(-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2(x-1)}+\frac{1}{2(x+1)}\right)\;dx&=\int dt\\
\frac{1}{2}\left(-\ln(x)+\frac{1}{2}\ln(x-1)+\frac{1}{2}\ln(x+1)\right)&=t+C\quad C\in\mathbb{R}\\
\frac{1}{4}\left(-\ln(\sqrt{x})+\ln(x-1)+\ln(x+1)\right)&=t+C\\
\frac{1}{4}\ln\left(\frac{1}{x^2}-1\right)&=t+C\\
\end{align}

For the IVP $x_0=x(t=0)$

$$\frac{1}{4}\ln\left(\frac{1}{{x_0}^2}-1\right)=C$$

IVP:

$$\frac{1}{4}\ln\left(\frac{1}{x^2}-1\right)=t+\frac{1}{4}\ln\left(\frac{1}{{x_0}^2}-1\right)$$

$$\frac{1}{x^2}=\exp\left(4t+\ln\left(\frac{1}{{x_0}^2}-1\right)\right)+1$$

$$x(t)=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{\exp\left(4t+\ln\left(\frac{1}{{x_0}^2}-1\right)\right)+1}}$$

We can have only positive numbers under the squareroot, thus:

$$\exp\left(4t+\ln\left(\frac{1}{{x_0}^2}-1\right)\right)+1<0$$

Let's assume we work on $\mathbb{C}$ to get a real solution:

$$\exp\left(4t+\ln\left(\frac{1}{{x_0}^2}-1\right)\right)<-1$$

By Euler's identity:

$$e^{i\pi}=-1$$
$$i\pi=\mathrm{Log}(-1)$$

where $\mathrm{Log(z)}$ is the complex logarithm.

$$4t+\ln\left(\frac{1}{{x_0}^2}-1\right)<i\pi$$

$t$ depends on $x_0$ but $x_0$'s domain is not the every single real.

The domain of $\dfrac{1}{{x_0}^2}-1$ is $x_0\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$

If $x_0=\pm1$ then there will be a zero inside the logarithm which tends to $-\infty$. Because there is an absolute value function inside the logarithm, every other positive and negative number will be defined in the function. Thus

$$x_0\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1,0,1\}$$

Let's cut the domain of $x_0$ into 4 parts and analyze $t$ with respect to them:

$$g(x_0)=\ln\left(\left|\frac{1}{{x_0}^2}-1\right|\right)$$

Let $a+\epsilon:=a^+$ and  $a-\epsilon:=a^-$

a. $\mathcal{D}_{x_0}:(-\infty,-1)$
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{x_0\to-\infty}g(x_0)=\ln\left(\left|\frac{1}{(-\infty)^2}-1\right|\right)=\ln\left(|0^+-1|\right)=\ln(|-1^+|)=\ln(1^-)=0^-
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{x_0\to-1^-}g(x_0)=\ln\left(\left|\frac{1}{(-1^-)^2}-1\right|\right)=\ln(|1-1|)=\ln(0)=-\infty
\end{align*}$$

$$x_0:(-\infty,-1)$$
$$g(x_0):(0^-,-\infty)$$

b. $\mathcal{D}_{x_0}:(-1,0)$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x_0\to-1^+}g(x_0)=-\infty \text{, as } x^2 \text{ is an even function.}
\end{align*}

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{x_0\to0^-}g(x_0)=\ln\left(\left|\frac{1}{(0^-)^2}-1\right|\right)=\ln\left(\left|\frac{1}{0^-}-1\right|\right)=\ln(|\infty-1|)=\ln(|\infty|)=\infty
\end{align*}$$

$$x_0:(-1,0)$$
$$g(x_0):(-\infty,\infty)$$

Between $0$ and $1$ and $1$ and $\infty$ the procedure is the same. to result in:

c. $\mathcal{D}_{x_0}:(0,1)$
$$x_0:(-1,0)$$
$$g(x_0):(\infty,-\infty)$$

d. $\mathcal{D}_{x_0}:(1,\infty)$
$$x_0:(-1,0)$$
$$g(x_0):(-\infty,0^-)$$

$$t<\dfrac{i\pi-g(x_0)}{4}$$

I thought i could do something with complex numbers here as the relation for $t$ is implicit, but i can't continue with this part. So i will just substitute back the 'domain' of $g(x_0)$ into the original problem.

Finding the proper numbers for the limits is kind of a guess-game for $t$. I hope the function between the two endpoints of the interval is at least $C^0$.

For $t\to-\infty$

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{\substack{g(x_0)\to0^- \\ t\to-\infty}}x(t)_+=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\exp\left(-\infty+0^-\right)+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{-\infty}+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{0^++1}}=1
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{\substack{g(x_0)\to-\infty \\ t\to-\infty}}x(t)_+=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\exp\left(-\infty+-\infty\right)+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{-\infty}+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{0^++1}}=1
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{\substack{g(x_0)\to+\infty \\ t\to-\infty}}x(t)_+=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\exp\left(-\infty++\infty\right)+1}}\stackrel{\text{the } 4t \text{ tends to }\infty\text{ much faster than }g(x_0)}{=}\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{-\infty}+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{0^++1}}=1
\end{align*}$$

For $t\to+\infty$

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{\substack{g(x_0)\to0^- \\ t\to\infty}}x(t)_+=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\exp\left(\infty+0^-\right)+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{\infty}+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\infty}}=0
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{\substack{g(x_0)\to-\infty \\ t\to+\infty}}x(t)_+=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\exp\left(-\infty++\infty\right)+1}}\stackrel{\text{the } 4t \text{ tends to }\infty\text{ much faster than }g(x_0)}{=}\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{\infty}+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\infty}}=0
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{\substack{g(x_0)\to+\infty \\ t\to+\infty}}x(t)_+=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\exp\left(+\infty++\infty\right)+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{\infty}+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\infty}}=0
\end{align*}$$

To conclude:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t\to-\infty}x(t)_+&=1\\
\lim_{t\to+\infty}x(t)_+&=0\\
\lim_{t\to-\infty}x(t)_-&=-1\\
\lim_{t\to+\infty}x(t)_-&=0
\end{align*}

To find the assymptotes of the function we need to find its poles:

$$\sqrt{\exp\left(4t+\ln\left(\frac{1}{{x_0}^2}-1\right)\right)+1}=0$$

$$\exp\left(4t+\ln\left(\frac{1}{{x_0}^2-1}\right)\right)=-1$$

But we know that the exponential function can never be negative on the reals.

### Thus the domain of $t$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

Which checks out numerically - https://www.desmos.com/calculator/seubjf5tem

Comment: This is a rather complicated solution. You get faster and without much discussion to a solution formula if you treat the equation as Bernoulli eqn., set $u=1-x^{-2}$, then $$u'=2x^{-3}x'=u\implies u(t)=u(0)e^t.$$

Comment: @LutzLehmann Oh yes, that's smart. It's just when i see a Separable Problem i tend to not try to look for different ways to solve it.