# confusion over statement: If $x' = f(x)$, $f$ is continuously differentiable, then all solutions are monotone or constant.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing, dynamical-systems, intuition, differential

Here's the statement:

---

If $x' = f(x)$, an autonomous scalar dynamical system for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, where $f$ is continuously differentiable, then all solutions are either strictly monotone or constant.

---

If we have $f(x)=cosx$ then $f$ is still $C^1$, it is continuously differentiable, and the solution would be $x(t) = sin(x)+K$ for $K\in\mathbb{R}$. Here, x(t) is not constant and it is not strictly monotone.

So, how does the statement hold? Isn't my example a counter-example to it? Why and how is the statement true?

**Edit**: I understand why my counter-example doesn't work. How can I go about proving the statement?

Comment: $x(t)$ needs to be a function of $t$ not $x$. The equation $x'=f(x)$ means $x'(t)=f(x(t))$.

Comment: the equation is equivalent to $dx/f(x)=dt$, check on [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%27%5Bt%5D%3Df%5Bx%5Bt%5D%5D&lang=es)  ... Where you took the statement from?

Comment: Specifically, the derivative _with respect to $t$_ of $\sin x$ is $\cos(x) \cdot x'$, not $\cos x$, so your counterexample doesn't work.

Comment: If you meant $x=\sin(t)+K$, then the left hand side is $x^\prime=\cos(t)$, but the right hand side is $\cos(x)=\cos(\sin(t)+K)$, so they aren't equal.

If you meant $x=\sin(x)+K$, well, that's an equation that you could (in principle) solve for $x$. The solution will depend on $K$, for example, if $K=\frac{\pi}4-\frac1{\sqrt 2}$ then the solution is $x=\frac{\pi}4$. 

Then, the left hand side is $x^\prime=0$, since $x$ is constant, and the right hand side is $\cos(\frac\pi4)=\frac1{\sqrt2}$, so again, that's not a solution.

Comment: Hint: If $f(x_0)=0$, then what is the solution with initial value $x_0$?

Comment: Draw a little picture to see where the solutions are increasing, decreasing and constant.

Comment: Similar questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3856695/solution-for-xt-fx-where-fx-is-continuously-differentiable-function/3856803#3856803, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3808538/prove-or-disprove-if-y-y-y2-and-y0-a-where-0a1-then-ayx-leq-1/3808591#3808591, scalar autonomous DE are not that complicated qualitatively.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof that illustrates a common technique for these kinds of arguments.

Suppose $x(t)$ is a solution to $x'=f(x)$.

Let's assume that $x'$ changes sign from negative to positive at $t=c$.

Then $x'$ would be increasing at $t=c$ which would mean $x''(c)>0$

However, with implicit differentiation, it follows that

$$x''(c)=f'(x(c))x'(c)=0$$ which is a contradiction. You can proceed with an identical argument for the case that $x'$ changes sign from positive to negative at $t=c$

Comment: i don't understand how that proves that $x(t))$ must be strictly monotone or constant

Comment: It's a proof by contradiction. We're assuming $x(t)$ satisfies the DE and is a non-constant function that isn't strictly monotone.